# How to send mail from Linux with To, From, Subject, and File Attachment

Tags: mutt, sendmail

I need to be able to send mail from a bash script with the following:
To Address, From Address, Subject, Body Text, and File Attachment

I can send everything just perfectly using mutt EXCEPT, no matter what I do the "From" address does not get set correctly:

```
    e.g. mutt -e "my_hdr From:${FROM}")...
```

I can also use sendmail or mailx but I can't seem to get the file attachment and the body text correct.

```
    e.g. sendmail -t -a file
```

Comment: The body comes from stdin. Any attachments you need to encode yourself and add to the body.

Comment: For the sendmail approach, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160200/4667

Comment: Some implementations of `mail` have a `-a` argument which can be used to attach files, e. g. `mail -s "Subject goes here" -a /path/to/file.tgz somebody@example.com < /path/to/messagebody`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `From:` and other settings in a configuration file. The body must come from standard input.

For example:

```
cat msg.txt | mutt to@example.com -F ~/.mutt_settings -s "this is my subject" -a file.zip
```

For the settings file, copy an already working settings file and change the From line:

```
my_hdr From: Super Man <me@example.com>
```

Comment: Hello Juancho... you mention a configuration file but I am not sure what you mean.  If you are talking about .muttrc I cannot edit this due to co. policy.  Can you elaborate further?  I am very new at this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods usually of building emails, over the system aka compatible sendmail interface or via PORT 25/TCP. No matter what programming language or scripting language you are using, you will find examples for both cases.

It is known that when using the compatible sendmail interface, i.e. directly via the system, and not via port 25, only root can change the From Field.

When building emails from PORT 25/TCP, you usually can pretty much build email body with any FROM: field as you wish.

Other option is setting it globally as @Juancho says for one server, but then you are limited to only one and one From:

The other option is sending them as root, which I do not advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code required to override .muttrc from a script...

```
    echo "THIS IS THE BODY" | mutt -e "send-hook . \"my_hdr From: TechSupport <TechSupport@SSDdude.com>\"" -s "THIS IS THE SUBJECT" recipient@somewhere.com -a test.log
```

THANKS!